# Determining the name of an unknown file in a folder

Tags: php, arrays, glob

I have lots of folders and each of them contains two files: one is called thumb but the extension is unknown and the other one I don't know.  My question is how could I get the path of the unknown image? Here is the script:

```
$path = 'images/2011/May/30/brfZ0ehnBKO/thumb.jpg';
$pathtofile = substr($path, 0, -9); //images/2011/May/30/brfZ0ehnBKO/
$thumbz = $pathtofiles."thumb";
$all = glob('$pathtofiles*.*');
$zip = glob('$thumbz*.*');
$remaining = array_diff($all, $zip);

$thefile = ???;
```

I want $thefile to be equal to the other file...

Comment: What *is* wrong with the PHP script? Does it not work? If yes, what happens?

Comment: is it legal in php to do something like you did in your first line? i mean a string without any quote

Comment: $path comes from a database i just simplified it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pathtofile = dirname('images/2011/May/30/brfZ0ehnBKO/thumb.jpg'); 

if ($handle = opendir($pathtofile)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if(strpos($file, 'thumb') !== 0) {
            $thefile = $file;
            break;
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}

var_dump($thefile); // null if no such file
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use double quotes when trying to output your variable values within your strings:

```
$all = glob("$pathtofiles*.*");
$zip = glob("$thumbz*.*");
```

See if that helps :)